# Typescript generic types

Tags: angular, typescript

I have an api that returns me a data as an object, the keys and values are different every time so how can I create a variable as `Generic` and then assign the data to my variable so my data looks like this

```
{all: Array(2), soccer: Array(0)}
{all: Array(2), basketball: Array(0)}
```

how you can see the api returns me two different objects. I can make a variable and assign to the variable `any` type but I dont want to do by this way, do can I create a generic variable for example `private _match<T>:T` and then assign my data to this variable. Thanks

Comment: you might be looking for `Record<string, any>`

Comment: Neex more examples, at least 4

Comment: Please consider providing a self-contained [mre] showing your use cases.  If you give us something that we can paste into an IDE to play around with, you'll have a better chance of getting a useful error.  Right now it looks like `{all: unknown[], [k: string]: unknown[]}`, but we don't know because your console.log output doesn't give enough information (it's an array but what kind of array?).  The answer to the question as asked is probably "no, that's not what generics do" but without more information there's nothing more concrete I can say.

Comment: If you do decide to [edit] with more useful info and want me to take another look, pls mention @jcalz in a comment to notify me. Good luck!